# What is the systemd service/unit name for mounting fstab entries

Tags: systemd

I have a somewhat complicated setup on my computer (a Chromebook) where in a kernel without an initial RAM disk is used to reboot into another kernel with an initial RAM disk using `kexec`. I have a systemd unit (?) file that successfully runs `/etc/rc.local` (as in it will be called), which is what I use to call `kexec`, but I need it to start after entries in `fstab` have been mounted. The first-stage kernel runs without any use of the display (I haven't figured out how to get it to do use the display), so I don't know if `/etc/rc.local` is being called before or after `fstab` entries have been mounted.

I copied the `rc-local.service` file from another place and it looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/rc.local
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=tty
RemainAfterExit=yes
SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I hadn't noticed the `SysVStartPriority` until now and assume that value it's set to would make it run last, but when I swapped out my kexec kernel for the normal one (which boots straight with a display), I noticed that the logs or the console output said that that parameter was deprecated. So, I need to specify a `After=` parameter to control when `rc.local` runs. What is the systemd unit/service name that mounts fstab entries?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `local-fs.target` (for local filesystems) and `remote-fs.target` (for network filesystems). There are documented in the [systemd.special manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html).

See also the `RequiresMountsFor` directive in [systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

Comment: I thought it would end with `.service`. Why doesn't it?

Comment: @Melab well, because it's not a service. There are a bunch of different types of unit files, services are just one. There are also mount units (which is what your /etc/fstab gets turned into in systemd, or you can write them yourself), device units, automount units, socket units, and probably a few more I'm forgetting. Then there are target units, which are used mainly as dependency simplifications/abstractions: instead of depending on the potentially dozens of .mount units that give local filesystems, you just depends on local-fs.target.

Comment: @Melab you might want to start with the systemd.unit manpage. Or `systemctl list-units --all`